# Why "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.Root is not a constructor"?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Anyone seen `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.Root is not a constructor (start.js:692 )` in the browser console?
I've tried resetting endpoints, pages, `hooks.js` and `jsconfig.json` without any luck.

Comment: did u solve this problem?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to answer (see below).

Answer (score 1):

The cause seems to be a breaking change in SvelteKit. I had to replace

```js
const code = request.query.get('code');
```

in my endpoints with

```js
const code = params.get('code');
```